# Samsung Galaxy Note 3 won't sync with google play

Tags: google-play-store, sync, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I just got my new *Samsung Galaxy Note 3 SM-N900,* but I've already got problems:

First, everytime I sync my phone with google it always comes up with sync error, I don't know how to fix this. I've tried removing the account then putting it back on but it still doesn't work.

Second is that my phone doesn't even have the google play app. When I go onto the website and try download an app it says that I don't have any devices – which I think is due to the sync error.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What is the error message for the sync error? Is there a code / number? Why does your phone not have Google Play? Did you change the ROM of your phone, or is it like that by default?

Comment: when you goto accounts through setting and then click onto google it says sync error, i don't know why it doesn't but it has google games, gmail, google settings. i don't know what the ROM is but i didn't change anything

Comment: Wait. If you can *sync* with Google (or at least have the corresponding settings), *Google Apps* are installed. That includes the *Google Play Store* app. According to the contracts ("MADA", Mobile Application Distribution Agreements), manufacturers must either install *all* GApps, or none. Did you a) cook your own ROM, b) installed some custom ROM, or c) played with "root powers" and deleted stuff? I cannot think of a d) option at the moment, but admit I might have missed something.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what Google Suggests to sync your phone:

**Change date & time settings**

You can try to force sync your account by manually resetting your time settings.

1. Open your device's Settings app Settings app.
2. Tap System and then Date & time.
3. Turn off Automatic date & time and Automatic time zone.
4. Manually change the date and time so that both are wrong.
5. Tap Home Key.
6. Open your device's Settings app and then System and then Date & time again.
7. Manually change the date and time so that both are right again.
8. Turn on Automatic date & time and Automatic time zone.

(Excluded 'deleting and re-adding your account' here as you already did this.)

Here are all possible options available by Google Support: [Fix account sync issues](https://support.google.com/android/answer/6212917?hl=en)

**Google Play Store**

In case you don't have Play Store App, you can download it from [apkmirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/) , choose a version and install it after downloading.

You will be ask to enable 'Unknown Sources' to be able to install [Google Play Store](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/), follow this to enable:

Open Settings - Security Settings.

Scroll down to 'Unknown Sources' check the box.

After installing Google Play Store successfully, uncheck the 'Unknown Sources' box.

This will prevent everything (except the Play Store) from installing apps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> More -> Application manager. Scroll down to Google Play, and hit "Force Stop". Start Play Store, and it should start up.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.  Once I turned off Google 2 Step Verification, it worked just fine.

Comment: Its not an answer as to what has Google 2-step verification got to do with sync issues?